# Application crashes when increase the images

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to load the memory of the android device. I have tried using drawable images but the app crashes as number of images increases. So I was thinking to make an app with following scenario:-

How can I make an android application whose wallpapers keep on changing after a fixed interval. Say I have 10 images and want each one to be displayed in the background of the android application after a gap of say 10 seconds. I would like to achieve this using a service, so that it keeps on working even if the application is minimized.
Since I am new to android please be thorough and show patience with me.

Comment: post what you have tried? else you will get lot of downvotes.. so edit your question soon

Comment: My main motto is to load the memory of the phone.... so I have tried using drawable images ... but app force closes as number of drawable images increases

Comment: then give the suitable question title & tell exact what you need

Comment: @ashishmishra you can use viewpager with time interval

Comment: @ashishmishra r u try the my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This temporary solution not good solution

In manifest file -> Use **android:largeHeap="true"** in your application tag

It will increase the allocation for memory size for your application.

```
< application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
.................................   
/>
```

Official document - 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use View Flipper to slide images and Also have a look at startFlipping() and setFlipInterval() methods in ViewFlipper class

For more check [this](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-timertask.html)

and for View flipper see [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/auto-flipping-of-viewflipper.html)